# Can I retrieve an SVN Log from a local copy?

Tags: svn, logging

My organisation ran an SVN repository server for 2 years. This server died in November; we didn't loose any files thanks to the local copies, but we lost the history, which is obviously a shame.

I still have my local repository copies and I'd like to know whether I can regain the SVN Log from this local copy. Usually for running SVN log a server connection is required, so the question is, is it possible to get the log without server?

Comment: I assume you've already gotten the backup lecture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally speaking, no: log entries are stored as so-called "Revision Properties" SVN on the server.

You can, however, try to extract log entries from *caches* of an SVN client you were using -- as far as I know, TortoiseSVN caches log entries somewhere. SmartSVN does that as well.

Comment: That's correct, but I assume when the OP is talking about the log, he meant the history/revisions and not the log messages.

Comment: Tortoise seems to have an offline mode, which will prompt to be enabled if you can't contact the server. It warns that data may be incomplete, but seems to have the log entries from the last 6 months for me.

Answer (score 7):

The log is not stored in local copies : those only store the current copy you're working on *(i.e. the last copy you checked out)*.

So, no, you cannot get the SVN log from a local extraction.